# How to fix this slow Postgres select query

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance, pgadmin, postgresql-9.0

I need a little bit of help with a PostgreSQL query. I have the following SELECT query which needs about of 30 seconds to run on a table with around 100.000 and 200.000 entries.

```
SELECT i.id, i.debit_nr, i.pat_id, i.pat_name, i.invoice_id, i.invoice_date, i.due_date, i.client_short, i.payment, i.payment_option, i.marker, i.comment, sum(t.Sum) AS i_sum, i.import_date 
FROM invoices AS i 
   LEFT JOIN invoice_items AS t ON t.invoice_id = i.id 
   JOIN jobs AS j ON i.job_id = j.id 
GROUP BY i.id
```

I figured out that the part which seems to be slow is only the SELECT on the invoices table, because if i run

```
SELECT i.id, i.debit_nr, i.pat_id, i.pat_name, i.invoice_id, i.invoice_date, 
i.due_date, i.client_short, i.payment, i.payment_option, i.marker, i.comment, i.import_date 
FROM invoices AS i
```

it needs almost the same time.

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=63048.71..65737.16 rows=110203 width=76) (actual time=1421.792..1785.528 rows=110203 loops=1)
  Group Key: i.id
  ->  Sort  (cost=63048.71..63577.52 rows=211523 width=76) (actual time=1421.772..1573.998 rows=211527 loops=1)
        Sort Key: i.id
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 19944kB
        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=24793.35..34938.02 rows=211523 width=76) (actual time=473.877..1010.362 rows=211527 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (t.invoice_id = i.id)
              ->  Seq Scan on invoice_items t  (cost=0.00..3878.23 rows=211523 width=12) (actual time=0.035..112.034 rows=211523 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=22123.81..22123.81 rows=110203 width=72) (actual time=472.566..472.566 rows=110203 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 65536  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 3592kB
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=777.49..22123.81 rows=110203 width=72) (actual time=7.784..334.883 rows=110203 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: (i.job_id = j.id)
                          ->  Seq Scan on invoices i  (cost=0.00..19831.03 rows=110203 width=76) (actual time=0.005..170.120 rows=110203 loops=1)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=705.55..705.55 rows=5755 width=8) (actual time=7.707..7.707 rows=5755 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 289kB
                                ->  Seq Scan on jobs j  (cost=0.00..705.55 rows=5755 width=8) (actual time=0.004..4.741 rows=5755 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.874 ms
Execution time: 1824.846 ms
```

The problem is, it doesn't matter if i add an index over the id field or all fields in need in this select.

How can I speed it up?

PS: It's PostgreSQL 9.0 on a Windows Server.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.0 has been [end-of-life](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  for half a decade now. You should really plan an upgrade to a current (and maintained) version as soon as possible.

Comment: "Sort Method: external merge  Disk" needs about half a second. You can avoid that by increasing `work_mem` - the Seq Scan on invoices only needs 170ms

Comment: "*which needs about of 30 seconds to run*" - no it doesn't. The execution plan clearly show it only needs about 2 seconds. The 28 seconds difference are caused by sending the rows over the network and the time your application or SQL client needs to _process_  (and possibly display) 110203  rows.

Comment: mh... i run this query with pgadmin on the same server... should this take 28 seconds to display?

Comment: pgAdmin is known to be extremely slow when displaying large results. But why do you _display_ over 100000 rows anyway? Do you really plan to read each and everyone of them?

Comment: no it was only a test, i have a client server application and the server get's the data from the database and sends it over  to the client... so it seems the server takes to long to process it, strange since other requests are running wuite fast... i will take a look further into this... thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Then it's your application that needs 30 seconds to receive and process those 100000 rows.

Comment: It's only 1.8 seconds, but an index on the FK *might* help.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the query using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT i.*,
       (SELECT SUM(it.Sum) 
        FROM invoice_items it
        WHERE it.invoice_id = i.id
       ) as i_sum
FROM invoices i ;
```

Avoiding the outer aggregation *might* help the performance (although Postgres has a good optimizer so that is not always true.  You want in index on `invoice-items, invoice_id, sum.  I left` jobs` out of the query because it does not seem to be used.

Comment: i tried your query but in takes the same amount of time...
as written above i figured out that it also takes that amount of time if i only do a select on the invoice table, without the join.

you're right in this case jobs isn't used because this is a query which is build up with different search parameters which can affect jobs, but for one operation i need ALL invoices with the sum of the items like the query shown above.

Comment: @pyr0t0n . . . Your issue appears to be the amount of data you are returning from `invoices` and not the other things going on in the query.